# Testing functions that use MonadRandom class

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to implement lawful, deterministic [`MonadRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom) that takes seed or predefined results as argument for the purposes of testing?

Given

```
yesOrNo :: (MonadRandom m) -> m Bool
```

Conceptually, during test, such function might be resolved to:

```
yesOrNo :: Bool -> Bool
yesOrNo = id
```

I thought I could implement

```
instance (MonadRandom ((->) StdGen))
```

or

```
instance (Random a) => (MonadRandom ((->) [a]))
```

But I'm starting to realize that such instance would be probably useless because I cannot thread StdGen this way.

Maybe I need a way to extend `MonadRandom` with additional operations so tests could control its behavior? Maybe State? I'm not sure what approach should I take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing `Rand` instance is already law-abiding and accepts a seed for deterministic behavior. Take a look:

```
> act = replicateM 10 getRandom :: Rand StdGen [Bool]
> runRand act (mkStdGen 1000)
([True,True,False,True,True,False,True,False,False,False],988833273 1336516156)
> runRand act (mkStdGen 1000)
([True,True,False,True,True,False,True,False,False,False],988833273 1336516156)
> runRand act (mkStdGen 1000)
([True,True,False,True,True,False,True,False,False,False],988833273 1336516156)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? There's `(RandomGen g, Monad m) => MonadRandom (RandT g m)` but won't that create another layer on top on existing `MonadRandom`? Or did you mean to propose signature change? I suspect that there are implications of having `MonadRandom` as the interface, which I'm not so sure about.

Comment: @sevo Since we know `RandomGen StdGen` and `Monad Identity`, and `Rand g ~ RandT g Identity`, that instance tells us that `MonadRandom (Rand StdGen)`. So if you have an action of type `MonadRandom m => ...`, you can in particular choose `m ~ Rand StdGen` in your test harness. (And even if you only know the weaker `(MonadRandom m, MonadSomethingElse m) => ...`, you can choose `m ~ RandT StdGen SomethingElse` to get an action whose random behavior is made deterministic/seedable.)